# Receptacle spacing when one is mounted tv

Tags: electrical

The contractor is putting in the cable and electrical for the TV at 5' high.  There is not other receptacle along this wall,  The 5' high one will be just under 12' from the other wall receptacle...Problem is- we wanted a desk on that wall- under the TV-- in the bedroom-- with a lamp and it will look strange to have the cord hanging down from the wall mounted TV-- mounted - to avoid the wires hanging from the tv..... any recourse.?. other than asking please..which I have done-- they will only do it if I can find a code covering this-- so i may be stuck with an extension cord from another wall- about 12' long.. or have it hang down from the TV-- ??

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Would you post a diagram of what your contractor is proposing?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Recourse with what? Why not have a second new outlet installed for the desk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no height requirement for outlets other than 210.52.4 . This limits the height to 5-1/2' to be counted in the spacing. as no point more than 6' away from a receptacle or 12' between them measured horizontally along the wall. 
If your contractor won't drop one down the wall from the TV outlet (at a extra charge for the additional outlet time & materials) I would complain. But at 5' and within 12' measured horizonaly along the wall this outlet meets the minimum code standard.

Comment: Thank you -- I might be stuck with the builder--He refuses--  I will plan to have this done after closing.  I would think the code could address this--- We put the receptacle at 5' to hide it behind the TV-- and not cords hanging down---- and then - if that is the only one along that wall-- I now need a cord hanging down for a lamp-- seems kinda crazy--  legal-- but not very practical .  Thank you again-- you answered exactly what I needed..

Answer (score 2):

This answer does not directly address the question, but may be relevant to the OP's final solution.

While there is a rule about 12 foot max spacing, I find that this is very inconvenient.  In practice you find that the best outlet for a task is behind the couch, behind the piano, behind a book case.

If I build another house:

- All rooms have minimum 2 outlets per wall.
- All windows have an outlet at approximately sill level where they are normally hidden by curtains.

When I redid my kitchen, I doubled all outlets, put in blocks of 4.  Our kitchen currently has 5 counter top outlets, 4 island outlets, and 4 knee high wall outlets.

Putting in extra outlets isn't very expensive.  Go wild.